# Divide all values in dataframe by the minimum value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

A simple dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  gene = c("PKB", "PKB_1", "PKB_2", "ESR", "ESR_1", "MKB", "PKC", "PKC_1"),
  b = c(1.8,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,NA),
  c = c(9,10,11,NA,NA,12,13,NA))
```

I am looking to divide all values in the df by the minimum value in the df, while keeping all columns as such. It is OK to remove rows where all values are NA.

How can I do this, preferably using *dplyr*?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also: the minimum value is `1`. Dividing by `1` doesn't make much sense, maybe update your example data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `dplyr`. Changed the `1` to `3` to better illustrate what is happening.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  gene = c("PKB", "PKB_1", "PKB_2", "ESR", "ESR_1", "MKB", "PKC", "PKC_1"),
  b = c(3,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,NA),
  c = c(9,10,11,NA,NA,12,13,NA))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(min=min(b,c, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(b:c), funs(min=./min))
   gene  b  c min b_min c_min
1   PKB  3  9   2   1.5   4.5
2 PKB_1  2 10   2   1.0   5.0
3 PKB_2  3 11   2   1.5   5.5
4   ESR NA NA   2    NA    NA
5 ESR_1  5 NA   2   2.5    NA
6   MKB  6 12   2   3.0   6.0
7   PKC NA 13   2    NA   6.5
8 PKC_1 NA NA   2    NA    NA
```

In base `R` you can try

```
df[-1] <- df1[-1]/min(df1[-1], na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Seems to be working for you, but gives an error to me! `Error in funs(min = ./min) : unused argument (min = ./min)`. Why is that?

Comment: The solution using base R is working perfect, which I already knew. Wanted a solution using dplyr to be used with pipe. But will stick to base R for this one, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
 df1 %>% 
 mutate(b = b/min(c(df1$b,df1$c),na.rm=T), c = c/min(c(df1$b,df1$c),na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(!rowSums(is.na(.)) == 2) %>% 
  mutate(minval = min(b,c, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(b,c), funs(./minval)) %>% 
  select(-minval)

  gene        b        c
1   PKB 1.000000 5.000000
2 PKB_1 1.111111 5.555556
3 PKB_2 1.666667 6.111111
4 ESR_1 2.777778       NA
5   MKB 3.333333 6.666667
6   PKC       NA 7.222222
```

Or with `purrr` and `dplyr` with 2 less lines:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(!rowSums(is.na(.)) == 2) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(b,c), funs(./min(df1[ ,map_lgl(df1, is.numeric)], na.rm = T))) 

   gene        b        c
1   PKB 1.000000 5.000000
2 PKB_1 1.111111 5.555556
3 PKB_2 1.666667 6.111111
4 ESR_1 2.777778       NA
5   MKB 3.333333 6.666667
6   PKC       NA 7.222222
```

Comment: Gives `Error in funs(./minval) : object 'minval' not found`. Strange

Comment: is there any chance you loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` ?

Comment: No, I have tidyverse loaded

Comment: what happens if you run the first 3 lines of te code? is minval generated?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably using only numerical column s:

`df%>%group_by(gene) %>summarise(unique (gene),"ColB" = b/min(df$b,na.rm=TRUE),"ColC"= c/min(df$c, na.rm=TRUE))`

Can avoid renaming / making new columns by removing names "ColB", "ColC"